# Unicode Representation

Tags: windows, assembly, unicode, x86

Currently I am working on calling up CreateFile2, from kernel32.dll from inline assembly. The first parameter this takes is LPCWSTR, and can be seen at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx.

I am running into problems with passing in unicode characters. From my understanding 0x0065 should be the unicode character for 'A', but I am getting a bunch of weird foreign letters.

I am trying to set ebx to be 'A.txt', then callup CreateFile2, but the file that is being created has the name '䙥硴t楆敬2'.

Below is the unicode values that I am throwing into ebx, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    mov ebx, esp
    mov byte ptr[ebx], 0x0065
    mov byte ptr[ebx+1], 0x0046
    mov byte ptr[ebx+2], 0x0074
    mov byte ptr[ebx+3], 0x0078
    mov byte ptr[ebx+4], 0x0074
    mov byte ptr[ebx+5], 0

    push 0
    push 2
    push 2
    push 0x100000000
    push ebx
    call eax
```

Comment: Take a look at the content pointed to be ebx before you push it.  You want `word ptr` and ebx, ebx+2, ebx+4, etc.

Comment: I just caught the ebx+2 thing right before you posted, but the mov word fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Also, `A` is 0x0041 and `.` is 0x002E.

Comment: I see this now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Characters (technically [code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_unit)) in wide strings on Windows are two bytes but you are building the string as if the characters are one byte. When you get UTF-16 wrong this way it [tends to look Chinese](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953).

You need to use the `word ptr` operand size and you of course also need to add 2 to the `ebx` offset each time.